# Logging of DBCC Commands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there are way to trace if DBCC commands are being run against a SQL Server database?

Specifically I am looking to see if the following 2 commands have been run at any point?

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

The reason is that the cache keeps emptying and I am pretty sure there isn't a great amount of memory pressure on the server.

I would really like to  rule out the fact that this is being done by someone and really is a genuine issue I need to investigate and/or add more memory to the server.

Thanks in advance
David

Comment: the error log might have cache flushes

Comment: Are you familiar with [Event Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453(v=sql.110).aspx)? I use this to monitor for DBCC commands in my production environments. I can post some code if you're interested.

Comment: I am not familiar with Event Notifications but I will be in the morning. Any headstart you can provide would be great.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an extended event session to find *any* `DBCC` calls, that have not *already* occured.  From your question it looks like you may have wanted to find ones in the past? Like others have alluded to there *should* be info in the logs on cache clears, and should read as follows (at least on SQL2014):

```
Date,Source,Severity,Message
08/10/2016 20:03:51,spid66,Unknown,SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Bound Trees' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' or 'DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE' operations.
08/10/2016 20:03:51,spid66,Unknown,SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'SQL Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' or 'DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE' operations.
08/10/2016 20:03:51,spid66,Unknown,SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Object Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' or 'DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE' operations.
```

For the future you could use this Extended Event definition.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [DBCC] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(SET collect_statement=(0)
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
WHERE ([sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([statement],N'DBCC%'))), ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_starting(
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
WHERE ([sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([statement],N'DBCC%')))
GO
-- Uncomment if you want to output to a target file and change the file path
--ALTER EVENT SESSION [DBCC] ON SERVER 
--ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'K:\Backup\DBCC_XE',max_rollover_files=(2))
--GO


ALTER EVENT SESSION [DBCC] ON SERVER STATE = START
GO

-- Don't forget to turn it off
ALTER EVENT SESSION [DBCC] ON SERVER STATE = STOP
GO
```

Will get you some information like this (my user and server name are redacted):

[image: XE display]

If you want a trace (SQL Profiler) definition I could probably throw one of those together too.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

An [Event Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453(v=sql.110).aspx) can be used to both monitor for DBCC command events and respond to them.  The script below creates all the necessary objects, which I would recommend be created in a separate database.

I've added comments here and there where appropriate.  Most of the script can probably be left intact, except for the `dbo.ReceiveDbccCommand` stored proc, which you will want to tailor for your needs.  If this solution doesn't fit your needs, you can simply drop the database.

```
--All of the objects can be created in a separate database.
IF DB_ID('DbaEvents') IS NULL
    CREATE DATABASE DbaEvents;

ALTER DATABASE DbaEvents
SET ENABLE_BROKER;

USE DbaEvents
GO

--Drop objects first before trying to create them (in specific sequence).
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.server_event_notifications 
    WHERE name = 'enDbccCommand'
)
    DROP EVENT NOTIFICATION enDbccCommand
    ON SERVER
GO

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.services
    WHERE name = 'svcDbccCommandNotification'
)
    DROP SERVICE svcDbccCommandNotification;
GO

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.service_queues
    WHERE name = 'queDbccCommandNotification'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER QUEUE dbo.queDbccCommandNotification 
    WITH STATUS = OFF;

    DROP QUEUE queDbccCommandNotification;
END
GO

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
    WHERE r.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND r.ROUTINE_NAME = 'ReceiveDbccCommand'
)
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.ReceiveDbccCommand 
GO

--Create a queue just for DBCC Command events.
CREATE QUEUE queDbccCommandNotification;

--Create a service just for DBCC Command events.
CREATE SERVICE svcDbccCommandNotification
ON QUEUE queDbccCommandNotification ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]);

-- Create the event notification for DBCC Command events on the service.
CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION enDbccCommand
ON SERVER
WITH FAN_IN
FOR AUDIT_DBCC_EVENT
TO SERVICE 'svcDbccCommandNotification', 'current database';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ReceiveDbccCommand
/******************************************************************************
* Name     : dbo.ReceiveDbccCommand
* Purpose  : Handles DBCC events (activated by QUEUE queDbccCommandNotification)
* Inputs   : None
* Outputs  : None
* Returns  : Nothing
******************************************************************************
* Change History
*   ??/??/2015  DMason  Created
******************************************************************************/
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @MsgBody XML

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Receive the next available message FROM the queue
        WAITFOR (
            RECEIVE TOP(1) -- just handle one message at a time
                @MsgBody = CAST(message_body AS XML)
                FROM queDbccCommandNotification
        ), TIMEOUT 1000  -- if the queue is empty for one second, give UPDATE and go away
        -- If we didn't get anything, bail out
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            BREAK
        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Login SYSNAME
            DECLARE @Success BIT
            DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(1024)
            DECLARE @MailBody NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @Subject NVARCHAR(255)

            --Get some pertinent data from the XML.
            SET @Login = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' );
            SET @Success = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/Success)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)' ); 
            SET @Cmd = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(1024)');


            --OPTIONAL: you can check which DBCC command occurred and proceed conditionally.
            --IF @Cmd COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%FREEPROCCACHE%'
            --BEGIN

            --Send email/alert.
            SET @Subject = @@SERVERNAME + ' -- ' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' )    
            SET @MailBody = 
                '<table border="1">' +
                '<tr><td>Server Name</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ServerName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' ) + '</td></tr>' + 
                '<tr><td>Start Time</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/StartTime)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' ) + '</td></tr>' +  
                '<tr><td>Session Login Name</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SessionLoginName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' ) + '</td></tr>' + 
                '<tr><td>Login Name</td><td>' + @Login + '</td></tr>' + 
                '<tr><td>Windows Domain\User Name</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/NTDomainName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)') + '\' +
                    @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/NTUserName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)') + '</td></tr>' +  
                '<tr><td>DB User Name</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DBUserName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' ) + '</td></tr>' + 
                '<tr><td>Host Name</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/HostName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' ) + '</td></tr>' +  
                '<tr><td>Application Name</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ApplicationName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)' ) + '</td></tr>' + 
                '<tr><td>Command Succeeded</td><td>' + @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/Success)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)' ) + '</td></tr>' + 
                '</table><br/>' +
                '<p><b>Text Data:</b><br/>' + REPLACE(@Cmd, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '<br/>') +'</p><br/>'

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                @recipients = 'You@YourDomain.com', 
                @subject = @Subject,
                @body = @MailBody,
                @body_format = 'HTML',
                @exclude_query_output = 1

            --OPTIONAL: log to table.
            --INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(EventDataXml)
            --VALUES (@MsgBody)

            /*
                Commit the transaction.  At any point before this, we 
                could roll back -- the received message would be back 
                on the queue AND the response wouldn't be sent.
            */
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
    END
END
GO

ALTER QUEUE dbo.queDbccCommandNotification 
WITH 
    STATUS = ON, 
    ACTIVATION ( 
        PROCEDURE_NAME = dbo.ReceiveDbccCommand, 
        STATUS = ON, 
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, 
        EXECUTE AS OWNER);
GO
```